# problem split expenses between people algorithm JS

Tags: javascript

I am making a function that divide expense between people in function what they have paid. But when I split 1€ into 3 people, the return is 0.33 each participant, I want to be
[0.33, 0.33, 0.34]
How can I make it

I was trying to get the total and view the difference of the result but It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Work in cents to avoid floating point issues.
- Take the floor of dividing the amount by the number of people, then distribute the remainder.

```js
const divide = (amount, n) => [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => 
  Math.floor(amount / n) + (i < amount % n)).reverse();
console.log(divide(100, 3));
console.log(divide(101, 3));
```

Comment: It returns wrong value when execute `console.log(divide(1, 3))`

Comment: @Jordy: [0, 0, 1]? How is that wrong?

Comment: The asker want result be `[0.33, 0.33, 0.34]`

Comment: @Jordy I specifically stated "work in cents". $1 = 100 cents... Unless you're saying we can divide 1 cent.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. But the asker ask about `€` instead of `$`

Comment: @Jordy It's the same concept. 1 euro is 100 cents.

Comment: This is so useful because later on I can convert the cents to €, THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You could sum the parts and take for the last the rest of the sum to distribute.

```js
const
    getParts = (value, length) => Array.from(
        { length },
        (s => (_, i) => {
            if (i + 1 === length) return s.toFixed(2);
            const v = (value / length).toFixed(2);
            s -= v;
            return v;            
        })(value)
    );

console.log(getParts(1, 3));
```

Answer (score -1):

Let `a` be the dividend, `b` be the divisor, and `n` be the number of decimal places you want. You can try to solve the correct division by looping it. When the last loop comes, you should subtract the total from the cumulative count

```js
let round = (num, n) => {
  return Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * Math.pow(10,n)) / Math.pow(10,n);
}

let divide = (a, b, n) => {
  let d = round(a/b, n);
  let res = [];
  for(let i=0; i < b; i++) {
    res.push(i != b-1 ? d : round(a - i*d, n));
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(divide(1,3,2))
```

Comment: why are we adding `Number.EPSILON`

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950/12715723), it will round the number correctly.